# Elastic search Multi_field type optimal search

Tags: elasticsearch

**Usecase:** Typeahead search:
I have a question with **Multi_field search**, the property with type I have is:

```
content: {
       type: "string"
       fields: {
             raw: {
                     type: "string"
                     index: "not_analyzed"
                    }
      }
}
```

So as and when I type I must be able to fetch the results, now **what is optimal way to search against content and content.raw field?**

I was thinking of a query like this?

```
    "bool" : {
        "should" : [ 
            "match" : { 
                "content" : { "query" : "post", "operator" : "and" } 
            }, 
            "match" : { 
                "content.raw" : { "query" : "postin", "operator" : "and" } 
            }
        ]
}
```

Is there any other better ways to search?
Right now I'm assuming its doing more like a 2 separate column search. Well actually its just one column (analyzed in 2 ways). 
So I assumed there could be a better way to search the multi_field types. (I know multi-fields are dead, but did not find better term)

Answer (score 0):

Yes This is the right way to query,
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/search-in-multi-field-type/28516
I posted the same is elastic and got an answer.